# Which version of openSUSE is closest to SLES11SP1

Tags: opensuse, suse

Which version of openSUSE is closest to SLES11SP1 in terms of package versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it's probably closest to OpenSUSE 11.2, but it's not an exact match.

Method: compare the package versions of [SLES](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=novell) to [OpenSUSE](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=suse) using [DistroWatch](http://distrowatch.com/)

Comment: SLES11 has been based on openSUSE 11.1. The difference between SLES11 and SLES11-SP1 are: upgraded kernel, glibc, X and some other key parts of the system, otherwise, it should be more or less the same as openSUSE 11.1.