# What is the relationship between SLED and OpenSUSE?

Tags: opensuse, suse

I have read that OpenSUSE is to "SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop" what Fedora is to Red Hat Enterprise Linux, but is there a document that explains this in more detail?
For example, from what version of OpenSuse is SLED 11 built? What are the update policies of the two distros?

(Edit: Someone asked something similar [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/which-version-of-opensuse-is-closest-to-sles11sp1))

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a single document specifying the similarities and differences between the two. However, as in the other answer; the [package versions](https://www.suse.com/products/desktop/technical-information/#Package) for SLES 11 indicate the current iteration of SLED is built from a heavily tested, cleaned, and reduced 11.3.

One difference between the two is, as in your question, the update policies. While OpenSUSE releases another iteration every 8 months (12.1, 12.2, 12.3), SLED remains on the same version for 2 to 3 years (10, 11), but receives a 'service pack' (a bundle of minor updates) usually around every 12 months (11 SP1, 11 SP2). There doesn't appear to be anything signifying SLES & SLED share a different code-base to what was 11.3, so any input on this matter would be appreciated.