# installing R - cannot find repo for SLE 11 SP3

Tags: sles, r

I am trying to install R for SLE 11 SP3. On R's readme pages it suggests adding a repo located at `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/R:/patched/` but there is no directory there for SLE 11.

I am on an AWS EC2 instance.

Will greatly appreciate help.

Comment: A brief tutorial on how to install R 3.3.3 on SLES11 SP3 http://hashprompt.blogspot.com/2017/06/installation-of-r-on-suse-linux.html

Answer (score 1):

That is old: OpenSUSE 13 is current; 12 has had no updates for a year or so, and as far as I know the release versions correspond to SLE.  According to the [description](https://www.suse.com/promo/sle/11sp4.html), SLE 11 would have updates if you have a support contract.

Considering the dates in the [download area](http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/), it seems that 13 came out late 2013, and 12 came out late 2011 (while 11 came out in 2009), and each release gets a few updates past the time when the next release comes out.

Further reading:

- [Which version of openSUSE is closest to SLES11SP1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/which-version-of-opensuse-is-closest-to-sles11sp1)
- [SuSE Linux Enterprise 11 vs. openSuSE 11.1](http://www.zdnet.com/article/suse-linux-enterprise-11-vs-opensuse-11-1/)
- [Suse Enterprise Desktop vs. OpenSuse](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/431122-Suse-Enterprise-Desktop-vs-OpenSuse)

Comment: Thanks... Luckily I found an old rpm and an old repository. But I am stuck with SLE 11 SP3 until my vendor certifies an upgrade :-(

Comment: You should provide your link